# In minted, how to reduce the blank space between the line number and the code?

Tags: beamer, minted, python

The following is example beamer file:

```
\documentclass[notheorems,serif,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Python code}
\newminted{python}{
    fontsize=\footnotesize, 
    escapeinside=||,
    mathescape=true,
    numbersep=5pt,
    linenos=true,
    gobble=2,
    framesep=3mm} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Mesh Data Strucrure}
        \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{pythoncode}
        import numpy as np
        point = np.array(
            [(0.0, 0.0),
             (1.0, 0.0),
             (1.0, 1.0),
             (0.0, 1.0)], dtype=np.float)
        cell = np.array([
                (1, 2, 0), 
                (3, 0, 2)], dtype=np.int)
        N = point.shape[0] # the number of triangle points
        NC = cell.shape[0] # the number of triangle cells
        \end{pythoncode}
        \caption{The basic data structure of triangle mesh.}
    \end{listing}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Finally, I get the following result in my slide:

[image]

My problem is that the blank space between the line number and code is too wide, and I want to reduce it. So how to do it? Thanks very much!

Comment: I can't give you a clear answer without an MWE, but `autogobble` option seems to be of help.

Comment: @CarLaTex  yes, you are right. I should give more information. I have updated the question.

Comment: As @yudai-nkt said, if you put `autogobble` instead of `gobble=2` it works. (To yudai-nkt: you could post an answer).

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. It works! Thanks very much! @yudai-nkt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `autogobble` option is the way to go. Here is the excerpt from the manual:

> Remove (gobble) all common leading whitespace from code. Essentially a version of `gobble` that automatically determines what should be removed. Good for code that originally is not indented, but is manually indented after being pasted into a LaTeX document.

By utilizing this,

```
\documentclass[notheorems,serif,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Python code}
\newminted{python}{
    fontsize=\footnotesize, 
    escapeinside=||,
    mathescape=true,
    numbersep=5pt,
    linenos=true,
    autogobble,
    framesep=3mm} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Mesh Data Strucrure}
        \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{pythoncode}
        import numpy as np
        point = np.array(
            [(0.0, 0.0),
             (1.0, 0.0),
             (1.0, 1.0),
             (0.0, 1.0)], dtype=np.float)
        cell = np.array([
                (1, 2, 0), 
                (3, 0, 2)], dtype=np.int)
        N = point.shape[0] # the number of triangle points
        NC = cell.shape[0] # the number of triangle cells
        \end{pythoncode}
        \caption{The basic data structure of triangle mesh.}
    \end{listing}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

will produce

[image: MWE]

Comment: `autogobble ` did not help

Answer (score 0):

`autogobble` did not help me, either.
What did improve the layout, was `setminted`, instead of `newminted`, and `gobble=2`, instead of `autogobble`.

> \setminted[python]{ 
> fontsize=\footnotesize, 
> escapeinside=||, 
> mathescape=true, 
> numbersep=5pt, 
> gobble=2, 
> linenos=true, 
> framesep=3mm}

[documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf), p. 16